# how can i make fixed tree view in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have treeview in asp website when click linked node it redirect the whole page the treeview not remain to the page. but what i want only to change the the main page the tree view must remain in all page like windows explorer. I'm using asp.net website please help me how can i do that?

This is my treevew.

```
Home
  page1
  page2
page3
  page4
```

Comment: You forget put your code and/or treeview.

Comment: i used sitmap for treeview

Answer (score 0):

Create a Master page that have tree view within the table as following

```
 <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="content-container" style="width:     1016px; height: 407px;">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
             <td id="content-left" style="width: 200px; height: 424px; border-top-style:      solid; border-right-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; border-bottom-style: solid;   border-bottom-color: buttonface; border-top-color: buttonface; border-right-color: buttonface; border-left-color: buttonface;">
                <!-- 

   LEFT COLUMN

-->
                <br />
                <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="455px" Width="220px">
                    <asp:TreeView ID="tvNodes" runat="server" Height="448px" Width="215px" ShowLines="True">
                    </asp:TreeView>
                </asp:Panel>

            </td>
            <td id="content" style="width: 736px; height: 424px; border-top-style: solid; border-right-style: solid; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: buttonface; border-top-color: buttonface; border-right-color: buttonface; ">
                 <asp:contentplaceholder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server" >
    </asp:contentplaceholder>
            </td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And load the page to the  ContentPlaceHolder1 on node click event.